# Add IDs to toasts - For Automation purposes

Tags: android, automation, appium, toast, android-toast

I am trying to ease the automation process with Appium by adding some IDs to the toasts I display in my app.

Is there a way to actually do this on Android?

Comment: Do you want to display pre-defined `Toast` messages on certain events?

Comment: I want to check whether a toast is visible on the screen or not. So I will need to find the view via its ID.

Comment: Ah. You could override the `Toast` class. Put a `isShowing` flag in it with a public accessor method. And maintain this flag by overriding the `show()` method of the `Toast` class.